# Date in response is different than from MongoDB

Tags: node.js, linux, mongodb, ubuntu, mongoose

I am using Mongoose as MongoDB client, with Node and I am getting the date in respnse with -5:30 time.

*Date in DB*

```
"createdAt" : ISODate("2020-02-18T05:17:43.368+05:30"),
```

*Date in Response*

```
"createdAt": "2020-02-17T23:47:43.368Z"
```

It is affecting my applications data. is there any way to get the date as it is in the 
DataBase.
Thanks.
Please write if more information required.

**Mongoose Schema**

```
const price = Schema({

}, {
  timestamps: true
})
```

**Query**

```
  return Price.find(obj)
  .sort({
    _id: -1
  })
  .limit(parseInt(query.size) || 100)
  .skip((parseInt(query.size) || 100) * (parseInt(query.page) || 0))
  .populate('item')
  .lean()
```

**Server timedatectl**

```
Local time: Wed 2020-02-19 12:47:29 IST
Universal time: Wed 2020-02-19 07:17:29 UTC
RTC time: Wed 2020-02-19 07:17:29
Time zone: Asia/Kolkata (IST, +0530)
System clock synchronized: yes
ystemd-timesyncd.service active: yes
RTC in local TZ: no
```

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB will convert your date to GMT time during saving. But if you pull your date again to local time zone you will have appropriate time.

The ISODate is in UTC.

The browser converts to local time zone.

Is this okay for you?

`z.toUTCString()`

Comment: Is there any way I can stop this automatic conversion and get exactly whatever is stored in the db as it is?
Can you share some solution for the same
Plus as you answered Date will be converted to local time, But my server and local timezones are same (Asia/Kolkata).

Comment: MongoDB always stores the date as UTC time. Answer updated. Can you please check whether it okay for you.

Comment: So to convert all the dates in the result I'll have to loop though all the Documents and convert to UTC?

Comment: I didn't understand the actual intention. When we save Date in MongoDB, it always stores the UTC time of the correspondent date.  Now time in India is 5:25. When saving new Date() to DB, it saves as 19 February 2020 11:55.

Comment: Then my GET query takes the value and print it on the browser, it will show 5:25.

Comment: What MongoDB client you are using ? I am using mongoose.
My database shows the date values in ISODate format.
And in my case it's other way around. It stores the actual time and subtracts 5:30 hours in response

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208124/discussion-between-nikhil-bhandarkar-and-ashwanth-madhav).

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB stores dates as 64-bit integers, which means that Mongoose does not store timezone information by default,so when you query the collection with server then the JavaScript runtime will convert your collection tag to your OS timezone (default local timezone)

You can check with

```
console.log(process.env.TZ)
```

So if you want your response same like database just set timezone to **utc**